# How to replace .formLogin() with .httpBasic() in spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

In our case we need password credentials grant type, but since it is removed from both OAuth 2.1 specification and spring-authorization-server implementation I want to use the default `AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE` authorization grant type but with some tweaks due to out case.

Instead Login form I want to use Basic auth since token will be requested by gateway service and we also will be secured outside and actually instead username+password we will use just username. So I need to avoid Login page since user will not see it and I have only machine-to-machine request.

The problem is that simply changing `.formLogin()` to `.httpBasic()` doesn't work. If I follow default pipeline with url in a browser then basic login form popup and after submitting credentials it shows up again and nothing happens. In the postman if I send same get request to /oauth2/authorize I just got 401 status code. If I authenticate with some another endpoint and then try to call get on /oauth2/authorize again I will get 400 instead of 401 but that's all.

So could someone help me with using `httpBasic` or suggest other ways to get token without getting Login page just with REST requests.

Answer (score 0):

`httpBasic` is not OAuth2. Password flow is weak, reason for it to be abandonned. It is also a poor user experience compared to SSO solutions that serious authorization-server offer now a days.

If you want to authenticate a robot in its own name (not on behalf of an authenticated user), use client credentials flow, it does just that: authenticate (as itself) a program you can trust to keep a secret actually secret (running on your infrastructure and not in a browser somewhere on the internet)

If it is users that you want to authenticate, just have your clients use authorization-code flow (for Angular, with [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client), or an equivalent for your client(s) framework(s))

Comment: We need separate tokens for each user. So client credentials doesn't work for us sadly. Regarding `httpBasic` - yes, I know that it is not in specification, but I want to use as much default flow as possible. I already found a way to implement password grant_type but it require a lot of code and workarounds that's why I don't want to use it.
Also for some reason it started to work (maybe adjusting session settings helped) so I should close this thread. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Password flow is weak, reason for it to be abandonned. It is also a poor user experience compared to SSO solutions serious authorization-server offer now a days. If you have an authorization-server, just have your clients use authorization-code flow to authenticate users, with the help of a lib like [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) for Angular (or an equivalent for your client(s) framework(s))